# Phantom build errors in Visual Studio Community

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have a solution that has been around for a very long time. It is a solution that has 20 projects in it. It is a mix of asp.net, classes and winform projects. All in C#. About 6 months ago, it started showing errors on build. Always in just one asp.net project. The errors are not real. If you click on the class file it references, the errors instantly go away. This can be a pain since it may complain about 20 different .aspx files. I have to open each one, click in to the file and the errors disappear from the list. Then I build. It may or may not build. It may then show new errors that I have to open more .aspx.cs files to fix. Eventually though, it will build. Even sometimes when it will build successfully and I can start a debug of the web app, it may randomly exception saying there is something missing, sometimes a method, sometimes a static variable. Building again will usually make that issue go away. Sometimes I just have to click build quite a few times, mixed in with some cleans and rebuilds to make the errors go away. This is all without changing any code to fix any of the reported errors. The errors always related to a class that is another project in the solution it is dependent on.  Whats is interesting is the only things it will randomly complain about where added in the last 6 months.  Other parts of the class it will never error on.

I have research this quite a bit and have tried various suggested solutions. I have tried:
Aligning all projects in the solution to build to the same .net version (4.8)
Deleting the hidden .vs folder and restarting Visual Studio
Deleting the hidden .vs folder and the .suo file
Removing all of the project references and re-adding them
Completely creating a new solution and adding all of the projects to it.
Checking to make sure the dependent class is building before the web project.
I have also tried changing just about every option related to build.
Deleting any cache related to visual studio

I also did a repair install of visual studio and installed VS studio on a brand new machine with the same results.

This is an example of errors. Not sure if it is relevant, but the project being listed should say AlertPaging, but lists an aspx page instead.

[image]

I am kinda at my whits end on this. It started out as annoying and wasted a few minutes of my day. At this point I cannot build successfully at all. Occasionally it will actually say it built successfully, but if I test the web app, it will exception with missing methods.